# c# lambda with join and groupby

Tags: c#, join, lambda, group-by, type-conversion

I have this lambda expression which actually works

```
 var d = DateTime.Now.AddDays(-30);
return db.Orders
.Where(o => o.CreateDate > d)
.Join(db.OrderItems, o => o.OrderId, o => o.OrderId, (o, p) => new { Order = o, OrderItem = p })
.Join(db.Customers, o => o.Order.CustomerId, o => o.CustomerId, (o, p) => new { o.Order, o.OrderItem, Customer = p })
.Where(o => o.Order.Status > 3)
.GroupBy(o => o.Customer.CustomerId)
.Select(o => new CustomerMonthSale
{
CustomerId = o.Key,
Price = o.Sum(p => p.OrderItem.Price * p.OrderItem.Quantity),
//Name = o.Select(p => p.Customer.Name)
})
.OrderByDescending(o => o.Price)
.Take(10).ToList();
```

But i have problem with this commented line. I get error message:

> Cannot implicitly convert type 'System.Collections.Generic.IEnumerable' to 'string'

Why? How do I fix this?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It is becuase you are selecting a collection, but `Name` is expicting a single string.
try this:

```
Name = o.Select(p => p.Customer.Name).FirstOrDefault()
```

Becuase after a `.Select(..)` you always get a collection (`IEnumerable`), by calling `FirstOrDefault()` you get the first item in that collection